# Largest feasible Crooke's Radiometer?

Tags: classical-mechanics

I will be working with a scientific glassblower to make a large demonstration Crooke's Radiometer.  I would like it to be as large as possible.  We will be using jewel pivot bearings to keep the friction low.

Is there a size limit I should be aware of?
eg.  What are the underlying physical constraints on this endeavour?
Any suggestions/tips for the design / construction?

Edit...My physics coffee buddy just mentioned that the force on the vanes is generated at the edges of the vanes via "thermal transpiration."  So I will need to design the vanes to maximize edge length vs surface area.

Comment: You better find out the limits with your glassblower, there is al limit to get the right vacuum in a very large bulb.

Comment: He says he can easily make an 18 inch diameter sphere or cylinder.  I am wondering if there is a maximum size for the paddles so they will still rotate.

Comment: Instead of going through a glass blower, I might suggest a commercial product, such as https://www.lesker.com/newweb/chambers/pyrex-bell-jars.cfm - the commercial bell jar places have long experience with the requirements to design for vacuum. Bonus points for finding an old deposition system with vacuum pump to use...

Comment: Neat project. You will need to get the Knudsen number right, a fancy way of saying the getting the pressure right. The size of the chamber  won't matter as long as you get the pressure right, although it may be harder to heat the vane uniformly and get the larger surface to a high temperature. With larger vanes you will need a better vacuum. So I think the vane size is more important than the chamber diameter if you have a good vacuum capability.